# Como cargo un multiselect desde BD con javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql, bootstrap, select, multiselect

estoy usando bootsrap-select (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) y no puedo cargar el select desde la BD con javascript, el select normal me cargaba bien pero desde que lo cambie por un multiselect no funciona, el código que me funcionaba para cargar un select normal era este:
`function CargarCboCarreras() {

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            "url": "FrmUsuarios.aspx/CarrerasBuscarTodos",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var json = $.parseJSON(data.d);
                var status = json.Status;

                if (status == 200) {

                    var cboCarrera = $("#cboCarrera");
                    cboCarrera.empty();



                    for (var i = 0; i < json.Data.length; i++) {
                        // <option value="1">Option 1</option>

                        cboCarrera.append('<option value="' + json.Data[i].IdCarrera + '">' + json.Data[i].Carrera + '</option>');

                    };



                    $('#cboCarrera option[value=' + json.Data[0].IdCarrera + ']').prop('selected', 'selected').change();

          



                } else if (status == 401) {

                    swal("Error", "No se pudieron cargar las carreras", "warning");


                }



            },
            error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);

            },
            beforeSend: function () {


            },
            complete: function () {



            }
        })
    }
```

`

Para inicializar el multiselect uso:

`$(function () { $('cboCarrera').selectpicker(); });`

Probé con este también: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect pero sigo sin poder cargar, soy nuevo en JavaScript seguramente me este faltando algo pero no se

Comment: buen día, podrías mejor en este caso poner el código, pero el que no te funciona.

Comment: Es que estoy utilizando ese código también, no se cual podría utilizar o que cambiar!